# Adding name of individual data frame to new column in merged data frame

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames, with each data frame named after patient ID.

```
df.list <- (1297, 2468, 3323, 4453, 4785, 6489, 7338, 8244, 9345, etc.)
```

Each data frame has data like this (this is very simplified, but it gets the point across):

```
A     B     C     D
1     8     4     2
3     4     6     8
```

I want to merge all of the data frames in the list so that all A values are in one column, all B values in another, etc.

However, I also want to add a new column which tells me which patient this data came from. So I would like to extract the name of the data frame (which is patient ID) from which the data in that particular row came from and add this value to a new column in the merged data frame. I plan on merging it using rbind, but I do not know how to add another column with the patient ID information.

The goal is to have the following information in the final data frame:

```
A     B     C     D     Patient ID
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: How is the data structured?  Do you have a list of data frames, and the names have the patient id in them?

Comment: @lebelinoz Yep, that's exactly how it is! There are variable number of rows in each data frame which is being merged into the larger data frame, so in the new data frame I want the patient ID from which the individual row of data came from.

Answer (score 1):

Using the input data shown in reproducible form in the Note below, `rbind` the data frames together.  The row names will contain the ID followed by a suffix indicating the row number so we can get the desired data frame, `df2`, like this:

```
df2 <- do.call("rbind", mget(df.list))
df2$id <- sub("[.].*", "", rownames(df2))
rownames(df2) <- NULL
```

**Note:** We assume this input data:

```
df.list <- c(1297, 2468, 3323, 4453, 4785, 6489, 7338, 8244, 9345)
df.list <- as.character(df.list)
Lines <- "A     B     C     D
1     8     4     2
3     4     6     8"
df <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
for(nm in df.list) assign(nm, df)
```